# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' odoo14

Tags: python-3.x, xml, error-handling, odoo

i was building a custom wizard and i get this error while refreshing my module in odoo
i want to build a wizard and get the data entered in wizard to another fields.
how to do that..?
Thanks in advance

```
from odoo import fields, models, api

class  CreateExam(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'exam.wizards'
    _description = 'Create exams'

    std_wiz = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='std.record',
        string='Student',
        required=False)
    std_subject = fields.Many2one('std.subject',string="Subject")
    std_marks=fields.Float(string="Marks")

    def save_btn(self):
        print("saved")
        return True
```

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<data>
<record id="examwiz_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">exam_view_form</field>
<field name="model">exam.wizards</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<form string="exam form">
<sheet>
<group>
<field name="std_wiz"/>
<field name="std_subject"/>
<field name="std_marks"/>

</group>
</sheet>
<footer>
<button name="save_btn" string="save" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
<button string="Cancel" class="btn-secondary" special="cancel"/>
</footer>
</form>
</field>
</record>
<record id="examwiz_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
<field name="name"></field>
<field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
<field name="res_model">exam.wizards</field>
<field name="view_mode">form</field>
<field name="view_id" ref="examwiz_view_form"/>
<field name="target">new</field>
</record>
<!-- This Menu Item must have a parent and an action -->
<menuitem id="examwiz_categ" name="Create Exam" parent="school_root_menu" action="examwiz_action" sequence="5"/>

</data>
</odoo>
```

error log

```
2022-02-19 13:10:25,416 18668 ERROR alfikodoo odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry 
2022-02-19 13:10:25,416 18668 CRITICAL alfikodoo odoo.service.server: Failed to initialize database `alfikodoo`. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alfik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\odoo11\odoo\service\server.py", line 1199, in preload_registries
    registry = Registry.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)
  File "C:\Users\alfik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\odoo11\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 89, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\Users\alfik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\odoo11\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 503, in load_modules
    env['ir.model.data']._process_end(processed_modules)
  File "C:\Users\alfik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\odoo11\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_model.py", line 2296, in _process_end
    record.unlink()
  File "C:\Users\alfik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\odoo11\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_model.py", line 1370, in unlink
    self._process_ondelete()
  File "C:\Users\alfik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\odoo11\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_model.py", line 1418, in _process_ondelete
    ondelete = (field.ondelete or {}).get(selection.value)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `ondelete` attribute for many2one field. From Odoo documentation

> ondelete (str) – what to do when the referred record is deleted; possible values are: 'set null', 'restrict', 'cascade'

For more information please visit Odoo official documentation about [many2one field](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html?highlight=many2one#odoo.fields.Many2one). For example,

```
std_wiz = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='std.record',
    string='Student',
    required=False, ondelete='cascade')
```

Comment: i tried this in my field but still getting that error

Answer (score 0):

If you're making an odoo module and you have a test document of that model saved in the database, and you then change the model, adding a `Many2one` field, then "upgrade" the app in Odoo, you will get this message.  I believe it's related to the record that was created before the Many2one field was added.

Solution for me was to "uninstall" the app in odoo, which cleared the test documents, and then install it again.